# Json запрос вешает приложение

Tags: json, api, arraylist

Коллеги!
Написал код, в котором хотел получить URl картинки по названию артиста на Last.FM. И что-то пошло не так... Подскажите, где копать? В момент истины эмулятор закрывает приложение.

Интерфейс делаю следующий:

public interface LastFMApiInterface {

```
String LASTFMURL = "http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/";
String API_KEY = "6c8dc87e402c8f96b8369f927ca0c1be";
String format = "json";

@GET
public Call<List<ArtistView>> getString(@Query("method") String method, @Query("artist") String artist, @Query("api_key") String API_KEY, @Query("format") String format);
```

}

Класс для выбранных полей:

```
public class ArtistView {

    private List image;

    public List<Image> getImage() {
        return image;
    }

    public void setImage(List<Image> image) {
        this.image = image;
    }
}
```

Сам MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private TextView textView, ImageViewUrl;
    private String ArtistName;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    }

    private void ImageArtist(){
        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(LastFMApiInterface.LASTFMURL)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();

        LastFMApiInterface artist_api = retrofit.create(LastFMApiInterface.class);

        Call<List<ArtistView>> call = artist_api.getString("artist.getinfo",ArtistName,LastFMApiInterface.API_KEY,LastFMApiInterface.format);

        call.enqueue(new Callback<List<ArtistView>>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<List<ArtistView>> call, Response<List<ArtistView>> response) {

                if (response.isSuccessful()){
                    List<ArtistView> ArtistViewArrayList = response.body();
                    if (ArtistViewArrayList !=null){

                        showArtistViewImageList(ArtistViewArrayList);

                    } else {

                        Log.w("onResponse", "Returned empty response");
                    }
                } else {
                    Log.w("onResponse", "Not success response: " + response.message());
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<List<ArtistView>> call, Throwable t) {

            }
        });
            }

    private void getResponse(){

        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(ApiInterface.JSONURL)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();

        ApiInterface api = retrofit.create(ApiInterface.class);

        Call<List<MusicModel>> call = api.getMusic();

        call.enqueue(new Callback<List<MusicModel>>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<List<MusicModel>> call, Response<List<MusicModel>> response) {

                if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                    List<MusicModel> musicModelArrayList = response.body();
                    if (musicModelArrayList !=null) {
                        showMusicList(musicModelArrayList);
                    } else {
                        Log.w("onResponse", "Returned empty response");
                    }
                } else {
                    Log.w("onResponse", "Not success response: " + response.message());
                    }
                }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<List<MusicModel>> call, Throwable t) {
                Log.e("Retrofit", "onFailure: ", t);

            }

        });
    }

    private void showArtistViewImageList (List<ArtistView> ArtistViewArrayList){
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append(ArtistViewArrayList.get(2).getImage());
        ImageViewUrl.setText(sb);
    }

    private void showMusicList(List<MusicModel> musicModelArrayList) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        ArtistName = "";
        sb.append(musicModelArrayList.get(0).getArtistName());
        ArtistName = musicModelArrayList.get(0).getArtistName();
        sb.append(" - ");
        sb.append(musicModelArrayList.get(0).getTrackName());

        //for (MusicModel model : musicModelArrayList) {
        //    sb.append(model.getArtistName())
        //            .append(" - ")
        //            .append(model.getTrackName())
        //            .append('\n');
        //}

        textView.setText(sb);

    }

    public void OnClick(View view) {

        textView = findViewById(R.id.music);

        ImageViewUrl = findViewById(R.id.URLtextView);

        getResponse();
        ImageArtist();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Рабочий код:

```
private void getResponse() {

        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(com.example.radiogomelfm.ApiInterface.JSONURL)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();

        ApiInterface api = retrofit.create(ApiInterface.class);
        Call<List<MusicModel>> call = api.getMusic();
        call.enqueue(new Callback<List<MusicModel>>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<List<MusicModel>> call, Response<List<MusicModel>> response) {

                if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                    List<MusicModel> musicModelArrayList = response.body();
                    if (musicModelArrayList != null) {
                        showMusicList(musicModelArrayList);
                    } else {
                        Log.w("onResponse", "Returned empty response");
                    }
                } else {
                    Log.w("onResponse", "Not success response: " + response.message());
                }
            }
            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<List<MusicModel>> call, Throwable t) {
                Log.e("Retrofit", "onFailure: ", t);
            }
        });
    }

    //get Artist & Track Name from response
    private void showMusicList(List<MusicModel> musicModelArrayList) {

        sArtist = musicModelArrayList.get(0).getArtistName();
        sTrack = musicModelArrayList.get(0).getTrackName();

        textView.setText(sArtist);
        trackView.setText(sTrack);

        }
```